# access return values of function when too many values to unpack happens

Tags: python

Occasionally, I made coding mistakes when function values list does not match. e.g.,

```
def f():
    return a1, a2, a3

a1, a2 = f()
```

f() can takes a long time to run, when it finishes, 'too many values to unpack' will be thrown. I have to fix the code and rerun for a very long time.

Is there a way to access the return value of f() when the error is thrown (within the python session or from the debugger within the python session) so I don't need to rerun?

Thanks.

Comment: `a1, a2, *rest = f()` to treat `rest` as a list of 0 or more items

Comment: No, there's no way to go back in time and get the values that were lost due to the error.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen They're not asking how to fix the code, they want to avoid having to run it again to get the result that was lost.

Answer (score 3):

Those objects aren't saved anywhere. This is simple enough to demonstrate with a `__del__` method:

```
>>> class PrintOnDel:
...     def __del__(self):
...         print('deleting')
... 
>>> def f():
...     return PrintOnDel(), PrintOnDel(), PrintOnDel()
... 
>>> x, y = f()
deleting
deleting
deleting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

So you can't retrieve them.